# Проблема с position CSS

Tags: css

Извиняюсь за глупой вопрос.

Не могу понять, как правильно перенести кнопку сразу под заголовок с левой стороны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```css
/* GLOBAL ------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif , Arial;
  color: #332E3C;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.containerheader {
  padding-top: 130px;
  /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------*/
header {
  background: rgb(216, 212, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(216, 212, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* border: 1px solid #708090; */
  /* height: 555px; */
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.welcome h1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

.logo {
  float: right;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  /* margin-top: 180px; */
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.vioboxlogo {
  width: 400px;
}

.button {
  background: rgb(35, 37, 140);
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  float: left;

}

.button:hover {
  background: #d32be4;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#about">О сервисе</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Как это работает</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Наши работы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Контактная информация</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="containerheader">



        <div class="welcome">

              <h1>Виобокс - это сервис подбора одежды для пышных женщин.</h1>

          </div>

        <a class="button" href="#survey">Заполнить анкету</a>

        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <img class="vioboxlogo" src="img/logoviobox.png" alt="Логотип Виобокс">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>





  </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам так нужно?

```css
/* GLOBAL ------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif , Arial;
  color: #332E3C;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation + .container {
      display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.welcome {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.containerheader {
  padding-top: 130px;
  /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------*/
header {
  background: rgb(216, 212, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(216, 212, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* border: 1px solid #708090; */
  /* height: 555px; */
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.welcome h1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

.logo {
  float: right;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  /* margin-top: 180px; */
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.vioboxlogo {
  width: 400px;
}

.button {
  background: rgb(35, 37, 140);
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
  float: left;

}

.button:hover {
  background: #d32be4;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#about">О сервисе</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Как это работает</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Наши работы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Контактная информация</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="containerheader">



        <div class="welcome">

              <h1>Виобокс - это сервис подбора одежды для пышных женщин.</h1>
              <a class="button" href="#survey">Заполнить анкету</a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <img class="vioboxlogo" src="img/logoviobox.png" alt="Логотип Виобокс">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>





  </header>
```

Comment: Да, похоже на то! Вижу что добавили flex - надо изучить эту штуку. Спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте ответ зелёной галочкой для того чтоб этот вопрос был полезен в будущем для других пользователей.

Comment: Не вижу зеленую галочку. А где она?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mbi22b, она находится слева от моего ответа серого цвета.

Comment: Увидел. Поставил.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @СтаниславКремса Хороший ответ (+) Не забывайте ставить сами плюсы за вопрос. Без набора определенной репы, вопрошающий не сможет вам поставить плюс при всём желании